# npm install complains 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command while node is in the path

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I have am doing Jenkins build now, but at some point of doing "npm install" I got a error message saying "'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." However, I do have node in my path and I have verify that but doing "where node" before npm install.

Both "where node" and "npm install" are located in the same Execute Windows batch command section of my Jenkins job.

I have read some posts. Sometimes this error is encountered for not handling the spaces inside the path correct. I do not have space in my path.

I also do not have convenient access to the machine for the build environment. I can only try Jenkins' Execute Windows batch command.

below is my build log inlcuding the error message.

```
npm install 
14:48:56 npm WARN deprecated ng2-bootstrap@1.6.3: ng2-bootstrap is renamed to ngx-bootstrap, please do npm i ngx-bootstrap -S
14:48:57 npm WARN deprecated hapi@13.5.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version of the framework.
14:48:58 npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.7: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated joi@8.1.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated joi@10.6.0: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated boom@3.2.2: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated joi@8.4.2: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated call@3.0.4: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated kilt@2.0.2: This module is no longer maintained.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated hoek@3.0.4: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated peekaboo@2.0.2: This module is no longer maintained.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated statehood@4.1.0: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated subtext@4.4.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated fast-safe-stringify@1.0.9: use 1.1.0+ see https://github.com/davidmarkclements/fast-safe-stringify/issues/4
14:48:59 npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
14:49:00 npm WARN deprecated boom@4.3.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:49:00 npm WARN deprecated joi@9.2.0: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated boom@3.2.0: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated call@3.0.2: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated joi@8.1.0: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated kilt@2.0.1: This module is no longer maintained.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated peekaboo@2.0.1: This module is no longer maintained.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated statehood@4.0.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated subtext@4.0.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:49:05 npm WARN deprecated wreck@7.2.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
14:55:08 
14:55:08 > node-sass@4.5.3 install F:\JENKINS-SLAVE\workspace\some_appcode\jenkins_job_code\app_folder\node_modules\node-sass
14:55:08 > node scripts/install.js
14:55:08 
14:55:08 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
14:55:08 operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What's the output of `where node` on the jenkins job?

Comment: this one:
F:\JENKINS-SLAVE\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\NodeJS-Windows-v8.2.1\node.exe

Answer (score 1):

Add nodejs new system variable to your PC under Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings

```
;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

After that, re-run command:

```
npm
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution was to clear the cache of Jenkins' VM and it will work. It was a cache issue of Jenkins.